# how to do an update if possible , otherwise do an insert in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to raise an exception when an update statement doesn't work.

eg:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET x = 2,
modified_by = userID,
WHERE prod_id = in_prod_id
AND loc_id = in_loc_id
AND invType = in_InvType
AND inv_status = 'N'
```

But if that statement didn't find the row it needs to update I want to be able to raise an exception or somehow identify it so I can perform an insert statement.

I tried doing

```
EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN

-- insert into.....
```

, but that didn't work.. cuz it never raises the exception as i thought it would.

One solution I found was to do a check and see if such a record exists in the table to perform the update.. But I want to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is a merge statement

See if this can help you : http://www.oratable.com/oracle-merge-command-for-upsert/

Comment: thank you . i will check it out. didn't know about merge command or upsert .. let me try that.

Comment: Agreed, `merge` is exactly the right tool for this.